# Solving the diophantine equation $1/x+1/y+1/z=1/2$

Tags: diophantine-equations, recreational-mathematics

I need help finding all positive integer solutions to the following Diophantine equation:
$$\frac1x+\frac1y+\frac1z=\frac12$$

---

What I figured out so far was that we essentially need to find $3$ divisors, $a$, $b$, and $c$ of some number $k$ such that $$a+b+c=\frac k2$$This is so that when we divide $k$ on both sides, we get $$\frac ak+\frac bk+\frac ck=\frac12$$which is the same as $$\frac1{\frac ka}+\frac1{\frac kb}+\frac1{\frac kc}=\frac12$$We know that $k/a$, $k/b$, and $k/c$ are all integers because $a$, $b$, and $c$ are divisors of $k$, so by definition, they divide $k$ evenly. Furthermore, I found through experimentation that for any $k$, we can automatically assume that one of $a$, $b$, or $c$ is going to be $1$. This is because if all of them were $>1$, then the resulting fractions would simplify to form a sum that was already previously covered by a lower case.

So essentially, in order to find the solutions of this equation, we have to find two divisors $a$ and $b$ of some integer $k$ such that $a+b+1=k/2$. Then we would have the solution $$(x,y,z)=\left(\frac ka,\frac kb,k\right)$$

---

My question is: Is this a standard way of dealing with Diophantine equations of this form? Or is there a better way that I am unaware of? I would also like to know if this equation has a finite or infinite amount of solutions. From what I worked out, there intuitively seems to be infinite solutions, but I am not entirely sure if you can keep finding divisors that satisfy the conditions as $k$ grows bigger.

Comment: Personally I would start by saying $\frac16+\frac16+\frac16=\frac12$ so the largest reciprocal is at least $\frac16$ and for other obvious reasons no more than $\frac13$. That give four possible values; if you subtract then from $\frac12$ you can do something similar with what remains and that way you get all the possible solutions.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more of this strategy? Maybe put an answer? Thanks

Comment: I am not going to do them all, but for example you might have $\frac15$ as the largest reciprocal.  Since $\frac12-\frac15=\frac3{10}$, the larger of the other two reciprocals is less than $\frac3{10}$,  at least half $\frac3{10}$ and no more  than $\frac15$, so might be $\frac15$ or $\frac16$; we have $\frac15+\frac15+\frac1{10} =\frac12$ and perhaps you also want the two other orderings while $\frac15+\frac16+\frac1{7.5}$ fails to meet the requirement of reciprocals of integers.  Do something similar with $\frac13, \frac14, \frac16$ as the largest reciprocals

Comment: Using the notation of the original post, if we take $k=30, a=10, b=3, c=2$, we have $10+3+2=15$. Dividing through by $30$ gives $\frac13+\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{15}=\frac12$. This gives a counterexample to the assertion in the original post that one of $a,b,c$ must be $1$.

Comment: Do you require $x$, $y$ and $z$ to be positive?

Comment: @paw88789 Just my luck that I stopped testing at $k=28$, I would've definitely spotted that if I just tested the next number...

Comment: @Thissitehasbecomeadump. Yes. Lemme edit that into my post.

Comment: @AidenChow That makes the question a lot easier,  as you immediately get an upper bound on $\operatorname{min}(x,y,z)$.

Comment: @Thissitehasbecomeadump. I do? Is it really that obvious???

Comment: Wait nvm I'm dumb... I see it now

Comment: Yes if $x,y,z>6$ then $\tfrac1x+\tfrac1y+\tfrac1z<\tfrac12$, and so you only get finitely many solutions with positive $x$, $y$ and $z$. In this case the answer by Reza Rajaei is simple, effective and to the point.

Answer (score 4):

The approach I am going to write below is maybe one of the most common and straightforward (as well as easiest) ways to find the solutions of the equation, restricting one of the variables to a certain range.

Let's assume $x, y \geq z >0$, then:
$$ \frac {3}{z} \geq \frac{1}{x}+ \frac{1}{y}+ \frac{1}{z} =\frac{1}{2} \implies 6\geq z. $$

On the other hand, clearly, $z>2$. Hence, $4$ cases happen.

---

**Case $1$: $z=3$**.

In this case, we have:

$$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{2}- \frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{6} \\ \implies 6x+6y=xy \implies x=\frac{6y}{y-6} \\ \implies y-6|6y;$$

but $y-6|6y-36$. Therefore, we conclude that $y-6|36.$ So, possible values of $y-6$ are as below:

$$y-6=1 \to (z,y,x)=(3,7,42) \\ y-6=2 \to (z,y,x)=(3,8,24) \\y-6=3 \to (z,y,x)=(3,9,18)\\ y-6=4 \to (z,y,x)=(3,10,15)\\y-6=6 \to (z,y,x)=(3,12,12)\\y-6=9 \to (z,y,x)=(3,15,10)\\y-6=12 \to (z,y,x)=(3,18,9)\\y-6=18 \to (z,y,x)=(3,24,8) \\y-6=36 \to (z,y,x)=(3,42,7)$$

---

**Case $2$: $z=4$**.

In this case, we have:

$$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{2}- \frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{4} \\ \implies 4x+4y=xy \implies x=\frac{4y}{y-4} \\ \implies y-4|4y;$$

but $y-4|4y-16$. Therefore, we conclude that $y-4|16.$ So, possible values of $y-4$ are as below:

$$y-4=1 \to (z,y,x)=(4,5,20) \\ y-4=2 \to (z,y,x)=(4,6,12) \\y-4=4 \to (z,y,x)=(4,8,8)\\ y-4=8 \to (z,y,x)=(4,12,6)\\y-4=16 \to (z,y,x)=(4,20,5)$$

---

**Case $3$: $z=5$**.

In this case, we have:

$$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{2}- \frac{1}{5}=\frac{3}{10} \\ \implies 10x+10y=3xy \implies x=\frac{10y}{3y-10} \\ \implies 3y-10|10y \implies 3y-10|30y;$$

but $3y-10|30y-100$. Therefore, we conclude that $3y-10|100.$ So, possible values of $3y-10$ (in this case, to be more precise, possible values of $y$ of course) are as below:

$$3y-10=2 \to (z,y,x)=(5,4,20) \ not \ acceptable \ (y<z) \\3y-10=5 \to (z,y,x)=(5,5,10)\\ 3y-10=20 \to (z,y,x)=(5,10,5)\\3y-10=50 \to (z,y,x)=(5,20,4) \ not \ acceptable \ (x<z)\\$$

---

**Case $4$: $z=6$**.

$$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{2}- \frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{3} \\ \implies 3x+3y=xy \implies x=\frac{3y}{y-3} \\ \implies y-3|3y;$$

but $y-3|3y-9$. Therefore, we conclude that $y-3|9.$ So, possible values of $y-3$ are as below:

$$y-3=1 \to (z,y,x)=(6,4,12) \  not \ acceptable \ (y<z)\\\ y-3=3 \to (z,y,x)=(6,6,6) \\y-3=9 \to (z,y,x)=(6,12,4) \  not \ acceptable  \ (x<z).$$

---

We managed to find all solutions.

Answer (score 0):

A common first step in solving such a problem is to clear denominators to get a polynomial equation. Multiplying by $2xyz$ yields
$$2yz+2xz+2xy=xyz,\tag{1}$$
so every solution to $(1)$ with $xyz\neq0$ yields a solution to the original equation, and conversely every solution to the original equation yields a solution to $(1)$. Note that all solutions with $xyz=0$ are of the form
$$(x,0,0),\qquad (0,y,0),\quad\text{ or }\quad (0,0,z).$$

A common next step is to find some divisibility restrictions on $x$, $y$ and $z$, and to take out common factors. This is possible because we have reduced the problem to finding the zeros of a polynomial.

Let $(x,y,z)$ be a solution with $xyz\neq0$. Let $D:=\gcd(x,y,z)$ so that $x=DX$, $y=DY$ and $z=DZ$ for integers $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ with $\gcd(X,Y,Z)=1$. Then
$$2YZ+2XZ+2XY=DXYZ.\tag{2}$$
From $(2)$ we immediately see that $X$ divides $2YZ$, that $Y$ divides $2XZ$ and that $Z$ divides $2XY$. This is quite the restriction on $X$, $Y$ and $Z$, which becomes more clear by considering
$$U:=\gcd(Y,Z),\qquad V:=\gcd(X,Z),\qquad W:=\gcd(X,Y).$$
First note that $U$, $V$ and $W$ are pairwise coprime because $\gcd(X,Y,Z)=1$.
Then we have
$$X=VWX',\qquad Y=UWY',\qquad Z=UVZ',$$
for integers $X'$, $Y'$ and $Z'$ that are also pairwise coprime. Now we see why the divisibility relations on $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ that we found are so restrictive: We saw that $X$ divides $2YZ$, where now
$$X=VWX'\qquad\text{ and }\qquad 2YZ=2U^2VWY'Z',$$
and $X'$ is coprime to $U$, $Y'$ and $Z'$. It follows that $X'$ divides $2$, and entirely analogously that $Y'$ and $Z'$ divide $2$. In fact, because $X'$, $Y'$ and $Z'$ are pairwise coprime, we see that $X'Y'Z'$ divides $2$.

From here we can reconstruct all solutions to $(1)$. We have just shown that $x$, $y$ and $z$ must be of the form
\begin{eqnarray}
x&=&DX&=&DVWX',\\
y&=&DY&=&DUWY'\\
z&=&DZ&=&DUVZ',
\end{eqnarray}
where $U$, $V$ and $W$ are pairwise coprime positive integers, and $X'Y'Z'$ divides $2$, and $D$ is a positive integer. Plugging this into $(1)$ yields
$$2D^2U^2VWY'Z'+2D^2UV^2WX'Z'+2D^2UVW^2X'Y'=D^3UVWX'Y'Z'.$$
Because $X'Y'Z'$ divides $2$ we can divide out $D^2UVWX'Y'Z'$ to get
$$D=\frac{2U}{X'}+\frac{2V}{Y'}+\frac{2W}{Z'}.$$
This means we can choose any three pairwise coprime positive integers $U$, $V$ and $W$, and three integers $X'$, $Y'$ and $Z'$ such that $X'Y'Z'$ divides $2$, and set
$$D:=\frac{2U}{X'}+\frac{2V}{Y'}+\frac{2W}{Z'},$$
which is then also an integer, to get a solution
$$(x,y,z)=(DVWX',DUWY',DUVZ').$$
Moreover, all solutions are of this form.

Comment: Huh, interesting that you decided to clear the denominators. I actually started with that equation and converted it to the reciprocal equation I have in the post. I was actually looking for when the volume of a rectangular prism equals the surface area for integer side lengths.

Answer (score -2):

It was necessary to write the solution in a more General form:

$$\frac{t}{q}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}$$

$t,q$ - integers.

Decomposing on the factors as follows: $p^2-s^2=(p-s)(p+s)=2qL$

The solutions have the form:

$$x=\frac{p(p-s)}{tL-q}$$

$$y=\frac{p(p+s)}{tL-q}$$

$$z=L$$

Decomposing on the factors as follows: $p^2-s^2=(p-s)(p+s)=qL$

The solutions have the form:

$$x=\frac{2p(p-s)}{tL-q}$$

$$y=\frac{2p(p+s)}{tL-q}$$

$$z=L$$

It is enough to sort through the various options.  $(tL-q)$

The overkill is insignificant. You can stop the search when the ratio becomes less than 2.

Comment: What is this "decomposing on the factors" strategy that you mention? Is there some resource where I can look into this further? Because I genuinely can't follow your strategy after you decompose on the factors. It looking very interesting though.

Comment: @AidenChow I always think that it is always better to solve the problem in a general way. This is a general approach. Since a fraction cannot be decomposed into an infinite number of different variants, this means that it is impossible to write a parametrization formula. The number of decompositions is finite - so it is necessary to decompose some number into multipliers and consider all options. The larger the number  $L$ - the smaller the others are and when one of them becomes less than 2. Further iteration of various options is no longer necessary.